# Proxy to Direct Connection

Tags: proxy, authentication

I access internet through a Proxy Server which requires Proxy Authentication. 
How do I setup a Direct connection so that applications do not need a Proxy Address ?

Something that could redirect all the traffic to the Proxy server automatically ?
I basically want to do this to use applications that do not have proxy options.

Comment: You could try the easy to use GUI tool [GrrProxy](https://github.com/Cadogan/GrrProxy)

Answer (score 1):

1)open this file through terminal

```
gksu gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

copy paste these line into the text file ,

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@proxyserver:port/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://username:password@:proxyserver:port/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://username:password@proxyserver:port/";
```

Save and close the file :)

2)Open this through terminal

```
gksu gedit /etc/bash.bashrc 
export http_proxy="http://username:password@proxyserver:port/"
export ftp_proxy="http://username:password@proxyserver:port/"
```

put the next two line at the end of the text file

Save and close.

3) login as root

```
 sudo -i
    export the environment variables.
    export http_proxy="http://username:password@proxyserver:port/"
```

and now you can do most of the things.
And for some applications u can change the authentication by changing the default settings to proxy settings,but u have to figure out which one u have to change.for example to Wget, you have to change gedit `/etc/wgetrc`, etc..